# how to iterate through this and sort

Tags: mongodb

I'm taking a mongo course that's using python language. I have to remove/delete each student's lowest homework grade. With this query, I pulled up the homework grades, and sorted them by student and grade

```
db.grades.find( { 'type' : 'homework' }, { 'student_id' : 1, 'score' : 1, '_id' : 0}).sort({ 'student_id' : 1, 'score' : 1 })
```

I arranged the query so that only the student id and score are displayed, like this. These are only the first 10 students. There are actually 400. Now I have to sort through them and delete the lowest grade for each.

Question is, how do I sort through this to remove the lowest grade for each student?

```
{ "student_id" : 0, "score" : 14.8504576811645 }
{ "student_id" : 0, "score" : 63.98402553675503 }
{ "student_id" : 1, "score" : 21.33260810416115 }
{ "student_id" : 1, "score" : 44.31667452616328 }
{ "student_id" : 2, "score" : 60.9750047106029 }
{ "student_id" : 2, "score" : 97.75889721343528 }
{ "student_id" : 3, "score" : 50.81577033538815 }
{ "student_id" : 3, "score" : 92.71871597581605 }
{ "student_id" : 4, "score" : 5.244452510818443 }
{ "student_id" : 4, "score" : 28.656451042441 }
{ "student_id" : 5, "score" : 23.29430953857654 }
{ "student_id" : 5, "score" : 41.21853026961924 }
{ "student_id" : 6, "score" : 81.23822046161325 }
{ "student_id" : 6, "score" : 89.72700715074382 }
{ "student_id" : 7, "score" : 63.35102050393443 }
{ "student_id" : 7, "score" : 85.56691619291915 }
{ "student_id" : 8, "score" : 66.42784200049636 }
{ "student_id" : 8, "score" : 67.29005808579812 }
{ "student_id" : 9, "score" : 16.60130789148128 }
{ "student_id" : 9, "score" : 75.29561445722392 }
```

Comment: Looks good so far, so what's the question?

Comment: @JohnnyHK thought the question was clear from title and context, but have updated it now to make it explicit

Comment: @JohnnyHK well, I'm working with mongo and python. I'm not sure if I should be doing this all in the shell (which uses javascript). Or if I should do three steps with python. 1) make the query 2) sort and remove the lowest score 3) reinsert into database.

Comment: If your course is on Python + MongoDB, it seems like the point would be to use .. Python :).  Rather than reinserting data, you should just be able to remove the record with the lowest score (I would include `_id` in your sorted results so you can do so).  I think you meant to tag this question `homework` rather than `homebrew` ... ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution written in JavaScript

```
var students = db.grades.find( { 'type' : 'homework' }, { 'student_id' : 1, 'score' : 1, '_id' : 0}).sort({ 'student_id' : 1, 'score' : 1 })

// Create a variable to track student_id so we can detect when it changes
var id = "";

// Loop through our query results. Each document in the query is passed into a function as 'student'
students.forEach(function (student) { 
    if (id !== student.student_id) { 
        db.grades.remove(student)
        id = student.student_id; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

haha, here's how I did our homework:

```
import pymongo
import sys
connection = pymongo.Connection("mongodb://localhost", safe=True)
db=connection.students
grades = db.grades

def delete_lowest_score():

print "grading nice?! look at these scores now!"

query = {'type':'homework'}
sort = [('student_id',pymongo.ASCENDING),('score',pymongo.ASCENDING)]
track = -1

try:

    cursor = grades.find(query).sort(sort)

except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]

for doc in cursor:
    if doc['student_id'] != track:
        grades.remove(doc)
        track = doc['student_id']


delete_lowest_score()
```

Comment: same solution. I'd like to see how other people did it, as I'm also using this course to improve general coding skills.

Answer (score 1):

```
connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost" , safe = True)
db = connection.students           
collection = db.grades      
query = {}
iter = collection.find({'type':'homework'}).sort([('student_id',pymongo.ASCENDING),  ('score',pymongo.ASCENDING)])
try:
    for doc in iter:
    nextStudentId =  iter.next()
        if ((doc['student_id']) == nextStudentId['student_id']):
            collection.remove({"_id":doc['_id']})
except:
    print "Error trying to read collection:" + sys.exc_info()[0]
```

Comment: neat and clean answer, but query={} isn't required there! @Sameer.nuna

Answer (score 0):

I've been taking the same course.

Now that the deadline has passed... The following seemed to do the trick:

```
import pymongo, sys
connection = pymongo.Connection("mongodb://localhost",safe=True)
db=connection.students
### s1 for sample (a cursor (iterable)); sort first by "student_id"
s1=db.grades.find({"type":"homework"}).sort([("student_id", pymongo.ASCENDING),("score", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
### c1 is a counter; note every 2nd record will be the lower score for that student 
c1=1
for d in s1: # d for document
    id1=d["_id"] # id1 is particular id
    if c1%2==0: # c1 divisible by 2?
       db.grades.remove({"_id":id1})
    c1=c1+1
```

This will modify the original collection by removing all the records with the lower of two scores for homework, leaving you with 600 records. Changing to `mongo` interface you will be able to duplicate all of the examples given in `Java` [here](https://education.10gen.com/courses/10gen/M101/2012_Fall/courseware/Week2_-_CRUD/Homework_2.2/).

I admit this a variation on @scicholas answer, just a little terser. I had trouble using a cursor at first as was iterating though records before running the above. If you're inspecting it interactively in Python, don't forget `s1.rewind()` to reset it first.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in C#

```
static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

        var db = client.GetDatabase("students");
        var col = db.GetCollection<Grade>("grades");

        var builder = Builders<Grade>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Eq("type", "homework");
        var gradedHomework = await col.Find(filter)
                .Sort(Builders<Grade>.Sort.Ascending("student_id").Ascending("score"))
                .ToListAsync();

        var sid = -1;

        foreach (Grade doc in gradedHomework)
        {

            if (sid != doc.student_id)
            {
               var result = await col.DeleteOneAsync(x => x.Id == doc.Id);
                Console.WriteLine(doc.score);
                sid = doc.student_id;
            }

        }



    }



    public class Grade
    {
        public object Id { get; set; }
        public int student_id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public double score { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bobbyz, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer, while it has well-presented code, could benefit from some context. Could you add some explanation of how and why this code solves the questioner's problem?